# Removing double quotes in a batch program in Windows 2003

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-server-2003, dos

I'm just past a beginning batcher (probably more like a butcher) and have been fighting with this far too long (I've found some suggestions and tried them but can't seem to make any of them work - probably UE).  I have a file on a Windows 2003 machine that I created in with a batch file (dir_list.txt) that looks like:

```
"t001wp" 
"w003th" 
"b005ku" 
"k009dp" 
.
.
.
.
```

I want to strip out the double quotes.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Search help for the "for" command and the answer is near the bottom of the help.  The %%~i will automatically strip the quotes.  If there are spaces in the quoted text you will need to use "tokens=*" to capture the entire string in quotes.  Hope this helps.

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (x) do echo %%~i
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

for /F "usebackq delims= " %%j in (dir_list.txt) do (
    echo %%~j>> new_dir_list.txt
)
```

**Update:** Edited after bobbogo's suggestion.

**Update2:** Edited to consider trailing spaces.

Comment: Annoyingly that space before `>>` will make it into `new_dir_list.txt`. You need `echo %%~j>>new_dir_list.txt`. Sigh.

Comment: This seems to nicely remove the leading " but not the last?  I think there may be trailing spaces. Sorry for leaving that out.

Comment: I think it is doing the same thing?  I'm not seeing the change (other than the space removed between the j>> )?

Comment: @adarshr: But with delims=<space> it also splits strings with spaces, so you get only `one` for the string `"  one two"`. You need to add the `tokens=*` to remove only the leading spaces

Comment: @jim it is `delims= "` now, was `delims="` earlier. @jeb yes you could do that, but I don't think jim has that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
type nul>output.txt
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%X in (my_file.txt) DO (
    set line=%%X
    set line=!line:"=!
    echo.!line!>>output.txt
)
```